# Given an input and get two outputs

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am using Tensorflow 2.4.0 and Ubuntu 16.04

Given this model

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(weights="imagenet", include_top=False)
base_model.trainable = base_model_trainable
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3), name="input")
x = tf.keras.applications.efficientnet.preprocess_input(inputs)
# more details - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning#important_note_about_batchnormalization_layers

x = base_model(x,
               training=False)  # training=training is needed only if there are layers with different behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout)
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(class_names), name="output")(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

My objective is given the input to get the value  of `model.get_layer("efficientnetb0").output`,
and `model.output`

if I do (a) (it does not give `model.get_layer("efficientnetb0").output`)

```
layer_name="efficientnetb0"

grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model([model.inputs], [model.output])
```

or (b) (it requires an additional input after preprocessing)

```
grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model([model.inputs, model.get_layer(layer_name).input], [model.get_layer(layer_name).output, model.output])
```

both works

but if I do

```
grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model([model.inputs], [model.get_layer(layer_name).output, model.output])
```

It gives exception:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'") at layer "rescaling". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

What is the reason, and is there a way for me to pass in just an input and get two outputs?